# need help extracting url from background-image in tag with simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php

am new in the scrapping world, Like to know if some one know a way to extract background-image url from a Li tag. here I place the code from the original html page:
Thank in advace....

```
<li class="first b-loaded" 
data-puntuacion="6,3" 
style="background-image: url(&quot;/carteles/255/primavera_en_beechwood_91776.jpeg&quot;);">
```

Comment: FYI, it's _scraping_. Scrapping is dealing with old junk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex

Regex to extract url():

```
url\(\S*\)
```

Input:

```
    <li class="first b-loaded" data-puntuacion="6,3" style="background-image: url(&quot;/carteles/255/primavera_en_beechwood_91776.jpeg&quot;);">
```

Output:

```
url(&quot;/carteles/255/primavera_en_beechwood_91776.jpeg&quot;)
```

[image]

Regex to extract the image:

```
([/a-z0-9_-]*).(jpeg|png|gif|jpg)
```

[image]

References:

https://regexr.com/

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php